# My reputation that I set as bounty did not return to me and I have not awarded the bounty

Tags: support, status-bydesign, meta

Ok so I've raised 50 bounty for this question

[WP_Ajax_UnitTestCase does not throw WPAjaxDieStopException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639955/wp-ajax-unittestcase-does-not-throw-wpajaxdiestopexception)

was not getting any attention so I re-add bounty after 7 days and raise it to 100

During the course of 7 days, I've earned reputation from this question.

Later on I solved my own question, mark my own answer as correct, bounty expired and I have not awarded the bounty.

But the 100 reputation as a bounty did not return to me, is this a correct behavior?

Comment: Is there anything unclear about it in the [help]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Reputation you offer as bounty is gone forever. You cannot award it to your own answer, and there is no way for you to request it back. You forfeit the reputation when you put up the bounty.

Comment: Ok thanks for that mate.

Comment: I like to think of a bounty as an advertisement or tv-commercial. You have to pay the advertiser up-front but if you don't sell any products you can't go  back and ask for a refund.

Comment: Thanks for the great analogy, makes sense.